# How to use nested loops to create tables

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have two lists, that I want to create a table with using jinja and for loops. Using one list and one for loops there are no issues.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
    </tr>

    {% for i,e in list_2 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
        <td>{{ e }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

Creates

[image]

However, when I try to introduce another for loop from another list this happens.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Pro</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
    </tr>

    {% for i,e in list_2 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
        <td>{{ e }}</td>
        {% for i in qtyyyy %}
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[image]

This is my ideal result. I have attempted to mess with the loops ending, but have not been able to correctly display it.

[image]

Comment: You haven't included the input data, as a python datastructure, in your question.  This would help you get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can solve the problem.
One solution would be to combine the two lists with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) beforehand.

```
list_1 = [
  ('(Retail)', 'Example'), 
  ('(1)(Distributor)', 'Example'), 
  ('(Ditributor)', 'Example'), 
  ('False', 'Example')
]
list_2 = [35.0, 147.0, 50.0, 180.0]
list_3 = [a + (b,) for a,b in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

```
<table>
{% for a,b,c in list_3: %}
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

But you can also use the current index to access the values.

```
<table>
  {% for a,b in list_1 %}
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>{{ list_2[loop.index0] }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: <td>{{ list_2[loop.index0] }}</td> Was the key here for me. For anyone else looking this was the issue. The list needed an index. Many thanks!!!